# Is there any API to get traffic signal light information in certain area?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, openstreetmap, traffic

I'm working on an Android project based on google map api, and now I need to dynamically show traffic lights positions near my location. But I found google APIs do not provide such information.

So my question is, is there any open API that I can use to get the coordinate of nearby signal lights if I provide my coordinate on the map? That will be really helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, OSM can provide this information. Take a look at the [highway=traffic_signals](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dtraffic_signals) tag and the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

If you aren't familiar with OSM yet then also read about its [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) in general.